# copy tables from one database to another

Tags: mysql

I have two Databases on mysql. They are used for completely different things and contain different tables. The problem is I need them both on the same server that can only host 1 db (and I **can't** change that fact). So I thought I can just use the same db for the to projects, since they use different tables and not overlaps.

One would think there is a simple way to do so.

There are not a lot of tables, so I can copy it manually one by one, but it seems that there is also no simple command to copy a table including all of the table rule's and restrains. (Working on a mac, so cant use sql server management studio).

It seems unreasonable that there is no simple way to do this. Is there one?

Comment: Where are the 2 databases now? On different machines? Same machine, different instances? Same server, same instance?

Comment: Why only one db?  Certainly not a MySQL restriction.

Comment: Backup and restore is the best way I can think of. Have a look at : http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php

Hope it help.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the source database name is databaseA and destination  is databaseB.

**Step-1**. Take dump of tables to be loaded to new host:

`mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --routines --skip-drop-tables --single-transaction --master-data=2 databaseA > databaseA.sql`

Notes:

- --skip-drop-tables is used to avoid accidental override of tables from  databaseA to databaseB.
- If there is no replication and active writes, you can ignore --single-transaction and --master-data options. (Harmless to keep them as well.)
- If you  have only a few of the tables to be dumped them  you  can specify list of tables (space delimited) after database name in above command as follows:

`mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --routines --skip-drop-tables --single-transaction --master-data=2 databaseA table1 table2 ... > databaseA.sql`

**Step-2**. Backup the destination database: (Just in case something goes wrong)

`mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --routines --databases databaseB > databaseB.sql`

**Step-3**. Load the database:

`mysql -uroot -p databaseB -hHOSTNAME < databaseA.sql`

Notes:
- Here HOSTNAME is the hostname/ipaddress of the destination

Just to add, if your databases are on same machine, (which is not the case here, but still saying) you can use RENAME operations to move tables:

`rename table databaseA.table1 to databaseB.table1;`

You can generate these SQLs  from information_schema database and source it to mysql to quick action.

Comment: Doesn't work! `mysqldump: unknown option '--skip-drop-tables'`

Comment: `--skip-add-drop-table`